# InstallShield LE does not detect registry entry launch condition

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, installshield-le

I'm using InstallSheild LE 2013 to create a setup project for a Team Foundation Server Tool and in the installation i'm adding custom requirement to look for Team Foundation Server Object Model 2012 is installed or not and base on that installation will proceed or come to a halt.

I'm providing following for the registry key entry to be searched 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\tfs\Servicing\11.0\objectmodelcore

But installer unable to detect it is installed and setup comes to a halt.I tried different approaches and key parts but does not seems to be working any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem installshield le does not support searching 64 bit part of the registry so if your dependencies write keys in that part registry search will return false